# Axiom of Regularity (set theory) - trying to understand it

Tags: set-theory

I'm doing my first steps in set theory and have a question about the Axiom of Regularity.

AoR states: $\forall x (x\neq \emptyset \rightarrow \exists (y \in x) x \cap y = \emptyset)$. What causes my problem is the $\exists$ statement (rather then having a $\forall$).

Assume we have a set $x=\{ a, x \}$. Then, to my understanding, this would not be a valid set based on the AoR, as $x$ includes itself. But it always holds that $x\cap a =\emptyset$ and therefore, from the formal perspective, the AoR would not be hurt.

I read different sources but never found a similar example explained.

One of my tries to proof that $x$ is a forbidden set by the AoR is the following.

- let $x_o$ (outer) = $x_i$ (inner) -- the indexes are just there for better understanding, so it is $x=x_i=x_o$;
- using the Axiom of Pairing we create a new set c (for collision), which is $c=\{x_i, x_o\}$;
- it is $c=\{x\}$ due to the Axiom of Extension;
- now $c\cap x \neq \emptyset$ as $x \in x$.

I have the feeling that this proof is either not the best way to look a the problem or it includes an error.

Any comment is welcome! Thanks for your time and help.

Cheers,
Georg

Comment: I re-read my question and I think I looked at it in a too complicated way.

How about:

(1) given $x=\{a,x\}$.
(2) $c=\{x\}$ due to Axiom of Separation.
(3) $c\cap x \neq \emptyset$ as $c\cap x = \{x\}\cap x =  \{x\}\cap \{a, x\} = x$.

Comment: This question is not suitable for this site, you may ask this in MSE. Anyway, $x$ cannot be an element of itself: apply the AoR to the set $\{x\}$ (which exists by the axiom of pairing) and obtain a contradiction.

Comment: Hello @EFinat-S - I'm sorry if this question is not suitable for this site, I was not aware of this. Can you please indicate, what MSE is? Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @georgmayer They are talking about [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Before you ask on MSE, let me assure you that this was covered before a couple of times at least.

Comment: No problem @georgmayer. The thing is that this site is for research level mathematics, and MSE is for other type of questions. But I know this is kind of confusing. Good luck!

Comment: @EFinat-S Your comment correctly answers the question, but let me point out that, if you're willing to use separation then you don't need pairing. If $x$ were a member of itself (or of anything), then you could get $\{x\}$ by separation.

Comment: Dear @AndreasBlass. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm extremely far away from being an expert on foundations, but it is a beautiful subject that I'm beginning to study in my (sparse) free time.

Answer (score 1):

Informally (and assuming AC) the regularity axiom means that there are no infinite chains $x_i$ such that $x_{i+1}\in x_i$ for all $i$. In particular, a set cannot contain itself as an element.

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for your kind answer!